# Can't remove strange "border" when styling WPF button

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpf-style

I'm trying to style a WPF button to have rounded corners and a black border. Following multiple examples online I came up with the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyBlackButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF282828"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="ButtonGrid">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid Margin="10,0,10,2">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Button Content="My button" Style="{StaticResource MyBlackButton}" />
```

This almost looks good, except the border isn't displayed properly at the top and bottom of the button, as you can see from the following zoom on the actual button:

[image]

To try to isolate the problem I added a much thicker border to see if there was any changes. As you can see on the next picture there is a sort of "border" inside the button:

[image]

So with a thin border, the border looks blurred at the top and bottom of the button, and with a thick border an inner border is visible (which I guess is visible on top of the thin border making it look blurred).

What is going on here? Why can't I get a pretty border around the button?

Comment: `UseLayoutRounding="True"` && `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`

Comment: Adding those two properties to the style (as setters) helped quite a bit, but not completely. Look at this image and you can see the top border is still not one black line: http://i.imgur.com/KdoMMur.png

Answer (score 0):

It is the anti-aliasing which is causing this.

Try setting

```
RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
```

on your button.

Comment: Won't this make the edges of the rounded corners jagged? (Not able to test this right now)

Comment: Yes it will! 

You need to pick one - anti aliased smooth borders which don't look perfect when you zoom in on them, or aliased borders which are perfect when you zoom in, but look more jagged generally. I don't think you can have it both ways.

Personally, I think your example that you originally posted looks fine at normal zoom levels. It's hard to tell with the dark gray colour you use, but if you set your background to red for example, the black 1px border looks fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" >

Comment: On which element?